# Unable to configure `emulator` command line tool

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I installed Android Studio on my Mac, added the following lines to my `.zshrc` file (and then `source`d it):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

but when I try to execute an emulator command (such as `emulator -list-avds`) I get this error:

```
command not found: emulator
```

I CAN run `adb`, so I know that my path is at least somewhat configured correctly.   Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the contents of the folder to make sure the emulator is there and with the right name? Files are some times renamed

Comment: Yup, the emulator is there.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm an idiot.  I didn't have the ANDROID_HOME variable correct. Updating  `.zshrc` this way will get emulator and adb working:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
```